# AWS Neo4j Connection Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I am using PuTTy to try to connect to AWS. I've followed the instructions at 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console

You are asked to get you instanceID, but then its use is not mentioned. Where does it go in the PuTTy setup?

My setup at present is:

- AMI ID: neo4j-community-.....
- Host name:   ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
- port: 22
- Authentication: link to my certificate, modified for PuTTY
- Connection>Data>Autologin>Username: I've tried numerous items here
  but none works.

The error I get is connection timeout. I'm using Windows 10 and have checked to ports for Putty in the Windows and McAfee firewalls ... Putty is enabled. I've check the ports at AWS and they are enabled.

I'm stumped and not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was adding/editing by SSH IP for my security group. This step was not included in the instructions mentioned above. When I did this, logon was successful.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PtBREh74r4 for more on this setup